# Pronunciation of Height Weight

Tags: pronunciation

Why is *height* pronounced as *hi*, but *weight* is pronounced as *wei*?

Someone suggest me a good book to learn such pronunciation rules in English so fast, not a huge book please.

Comment: If it's any consolation, this also makes no sense to us native speakers.  :)

Comment: You have it backwards. Spelling is an attempt to represent pronunciation; pronunciation does not follow rules which are dependent on spelling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In English, the letters *eigh* usually make the “long a” sound, as in *eight, weighty, freight, neighbor, sleigh*, and *inveigh*.

Also, the letters *igh* often make the “long i” sound, as in *sigh, thigh, right*, and *bright*.

In English, exceptions abound. I don’t know how *height* got its extra *e*. Neither do dictionaries, apparently; [Etymonline](https://www.etymonline.com/word/height) says:

> Century Dictionary says "there is no reason for the distinction of vowel between *high* and *height*."

As for why words are spelled they way that they are, sometimes word origin is a factor.

You can learn a few rules that will steer you in the right direction most of the time, but only few rules have no exceptions.

Spelling has always been vexing in English, even for natives.

Comment: Additional vexation - 'ough'... ought [ort] bough [bow] rough [ruff] through [throo] & just when you think you've got the hang of it, the old BBC commentator Frank Bough [boff]. ;)

Comment: @Tetsujin - I wasn’t going to go there, but other good examples include *earth, hearth, bread,* and *bead*, not to mention _blood, food,_ and _foot_.